# How is regex_match with char* expected to work?

Tags: regex, c++11, standard-library

The standard library defines [regex_match](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/) against a simple char* string.  Furthermore, regex_match returns true only when the *entire* string matches, yet this function doesn't take a length parameter for the char* string.  How does regex_match work in this case?

The function prototype:

```
 bool regex_match (const charT* s, const basic_regex<charT,traits>& rgx,
      regex_constants::match_flag_type flags = regex_constants::match_default);
```

Comment: It looks for the null terminator, like all other string functions that take `char *`.